# Partition sum:A Problem on probability

Tags: probability

A and B pick up a handful of rice from a bag containing 1kg(first A and then B).They weigh them and replace.Repeating the experiment,they find that on the average they pick up $w_a$ and $w_b$ of rice.Show that if they would have counted the rice grains and multiplied the numbers they would have obtained an average $w_aw_bN^2(1-\frac{1}{N})$ where 1 kg contains N grains.[Negligible correlation for large N]

Comment: There's not enough information here.  What do you know about the distributions?

Comment: What distribution does the physical problem indicate?May be binomial.

Comment: I would guess based on the answer it is binomial, but I didn't see that specified.